# Prove that function $f(x)=\ln{2-x\over x+2}$ is odd

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Please prove that function $f(x)=\ln{2-x\over x+2}: (-2,2) \to \Bbb R$ is odd.

Comment: Do you know the definition of an odd function?

Comment: Just read it... but thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

$$ f(-x) = \log \left(\frac{2+x}{2-x} \right) = -\log \left(\frac{2-x}{2+x} \right) = -f(x)
$$

Comment: Please consider not giving such a detailed and complete answer to a question phrased in this manner.

Comment: Could you please tell me what is wrong with my manner?

Comment: @Skoutas You should include your own thoughts and efforts in your question: This isn't a do-my-homework site. Show what you've tried, what background you know, and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's not a homework... I'm just learning Math and it is really interesting for me